# How to simulate Real Time Interrupt in 68HC11 THRSim11 simulator

Tags: microcontroller

how do you simulate the RTI (Real Time Interrupt) in the 68HC11 THRSim11 simulator (see http://www.hc11.demon.nl/thrsim11/thrsim11.htm)? the following program works at the 68HC11 module but not in THRSim11. It's a test program to read from Analog to Digital Converter and display results to serial port using RTI.  I tried the RTI interrupt vector 00EB and FFF0.  My chip is the 68H711E9 with the following memory map.

[image]

I expected the THRSim11 to simulate the interrupt vector. When running the "again BRA again" just before CLI (enable Interrupt).  It must be running the subroutine that reads from ADC and display to serial. It works perfectly in my 68HC711E9 Evaluation board with buffalo

```
REGBS   EQU     $1000       ;start of registers
BAUD    EQU REGBS+$2B   ;sci baud reg
SCCR1   EQU REGBS+$2C   ;sci control1 reg
SCCR2   EQU REGBS+$2D   ;sci control2 reg
SCSR    EQU REGBS+$2E   ;sci status reg
SCDR    EQU REGBS+$2F   ;sci data reg
TMSK2   EQU REGBS+$24   ;Timer Interrupt Mask Register 2
TFLG2   EQU REGBS+$25   ;Timer Interrupt Flag Register 2
ADR3    EQU $1033       ;ADC address 3
OPTION  EQU     $1039       ;ADC enable
SCS     EQU     $2E     ;SCSR low bit
ADCTL   EQU     $1030       ;ADC setting
ADCT    EQU $30     ;ADC setting low bit
PACTL   EQU     $1026       ;Pulse Accumulator control


***************************************************************
* Main program starts here *
***************************************************************
    ORG $0110
*   ORG $E000
start   LDS #$01FF  ;set stack pointer
    JSR ONSCI   ;initialize serial port
    JSR t_init  ;initialize timer
    CLI     ;enable interrupts
again   BRA again

************************************************************
*   t_init - Initialize the RTI timer          
************************************************************
t_init  LDAA       #$01         ; set PTR1 and PTR0 to 0 and 1
        STAA       PACTL       ;which leads to an RTI rate of 8.19 ms
        LDAA       #$40
        STAA       TFLG2       ;clears RTIF flag (write 1 in it!)
        STAA       TMSK2      ;sets RTII to allow interruptssec
    RTS

************************************************************
*  ADC_SERIAL - timer overflow interrupt service routine
************************************************************
ADC_SERIAL  
        LDX     #REGBS
        LDAA    #%00010010
        STAA    ADCTL
        LDAB    #6
ADF00       DECB
        BNE     ADF00


        ldaa    ADR3          ; read ADC value 
            ldab    SCSR           ; read first Status
        staa    SCDR           ; save in TX Register
BUFFS       BRCLR SCS,X #$80  BUFFS
        
CLRFLG      LDAA       #$40
                STAA       TFLG2       ;clear RTIF
        RTI                ;return from ISR

************************************************************
*   ONSCI() - Initialize the SCI for 9600
*                 baud at 8 MHz 
************************************************************
ONSCI    LDAA #$30
         STAA BAUD        baud register
         LDAA #$00
         STAA SCCR1
         LDAA #$0C
         STAA SCCR2       enable

       LDAA     #%10011010             ; enable the ADC
       STAA     OPTION

       RTS



*   Interrupt Vectors for BUFALO monitor
*   ORG $FFF0        ;RTI vector for microcontroller
*
    ORG $00EB       ;Real Time Interrupt under Buffalo monitor
    JMP ADC_SERIAL    ;this instruction is executed every
*               time there is a timer overflow
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you mixed up "vector table" and "jump table". The HC11 expects an address at $FFF0, not an instruction.

In contrast, the Buffalo monitor expects an instruction at $00EB.

```s
    ORG $FFF0        ;RTI vector for microcontroller
    FDB ADC_SERIAL

    ORG $FFFE        ;Reset vector for microcontroller
    FDB start
```

As you will note, the same holds true for the reset vector at $FFFE.

With these changes it works for me. Be aware that the simulation is really slow<sup>*</sup>, depending on the number and kind of views opened.

*Another side note: You send the single byte of conversion result without further processing. The serial receiver view of the simulator will try to interpret this byte as an ASCII character, and only if it fails, show a decimal number in angles. You might want to consider to convert the conversion result into a human readable value. The most simple solution may be a hex representation.*

---

**EDIT:**

*) A simulator needs to be factors faster than the original machine, depending on the specific implementation of the simulation. In this case, they seem to have used a quite slow way. The [documentation](http://www.hc11.demon.nl/thrsim11/faq.htm) has some words on this. To gain some speed, close any view you don't need, and use the fastest PC you can get. To gain some understanding, think about how slow a simulation would be if it will simulate the analog electronics with each semiconductor of the chip. And even that is just a model, the "real" world currently starts at quantum mechanics.

Without further measure, you cannot use Buffalo's jump table entries, because the Buffalo monitor is not included in the simulator.

If you want to use an unmodified version of your firmware, you will need to add at least the used parts of the Buffalo monitor. If you have the monitor as a file loadable by the simulator, you might want to load it before loading your application.

The least you could do is to provide the jump table yourself, placing the appropriate address of the jump in the vector:

```s
    ORG $FFF0        ;RTI vector for microcontroller
    FDB $00EB
```

The "problem" with the ASCII interpretation becomes visible, if values of printable characters are sent. Put the slider in the first third, and you will see some letter or digit or punctuation. Slide it minimally up and down for other characters. Yes, terminals can be dumb, and this one is no exception. Actually it is a little bit smart and shows the printable characters instead of their ASCII value. Additionally it knows at least CR (carriage return, $0D, decimal 13) and LF (line feed, $0A, decimal 10). You might want to write a little test program that sends "Hello, world", CR, LF. Or another experiment that sends all values from $00 to $FF.

The meaning of a value always depends on its interpretation. This terminal interprets values as ASCII characters, if possible.

Comment: See the little edit, and: Yes, since the simulator seems to run as fast as possible, the speed of the computer determines the speed of the simulation.

Comment: Actually, since SO reminds me, I see all your comments. "Unfortunately" I need to work for a living, so my spare time is quite limited. (Fortunately I love what I do.) But I'll look into it, promised.